# Interapp communication between .net and vb6

Tags: .net, vb6, communication

I saw a good article explaining how to have .net apps communicate directly with each other (http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/10/605.aspx), but it involved overriding the WndProc method in your form which I obviously can't do in vb6.

Do any other methods of inter-application communication exist that could be utilized in vb6?

I am about to start a new project in .net, but there are vb6 forms I will not be able to port as soon as I will need them.  After considering a couple of different designs I've decided that it may be best to just let the vb6 app run in the background and, when notified to do so, it could present any forms I need it to and then notify the .net application when the form has been closed.

Comment: Also, would prefer something that doesn't require any extra dependencies... for example I don't want to have to setup msmq or anything like that if I can avoid it.

Comment: Overriding the window proc is very possible in VB6, just look at subclassing.

Comment: @Deanna, thanks for that.  I found a really great piece of code using pipes that does just what I want, but I will definitely keep this in mind in case I ever have a need for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many alternatives.  If you say more about your requirements, I can provide a more detailed answer.

In the mean time, have a look at named pipes:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/871044

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx

If your programs reside on different servers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx

They are a reliable method of inter-process communication that do not require any specific OS setup, available to both .NET and VB6.

Comment: Thanks.  I added some info about what I'm trying to accomplish in my post.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish that with named pipes.  Just use pipes two-way to send the messages "Show form X" to VB6, and "Done with form X" back to .NET.

Comment: Yeah this looks like a good way to do it.  I'm following the example in the first link you posted but writing in c#.  One thing I'm not sure about is how to express a hexadecimal value like &H80S in c#.  I know in c# you prefix them with '0x', but do you know what the S on the end of that is all about?

Comment: That would be 0x80.  I think S assigns to a signed type.  If you just use a (signed) int you should get the same result `int i = 0x80`.

Comment: Your first link uses P/Invoke to call the Win32 API. Surely its easier to use the support built into .Net, as in your 3rd link?

Comment: @MarkJ Yeah, the xample inthe first link looked pretty short and straightforward so I just started going through it before I got to the last link... I think I will definitely go with the built in support though :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make your VB6 EXE an ActiveX EXE (COM server) and then have the .Net component call it via COM interop. I.e. just [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwys3b23.aspx) to the VB6 EXE on the COM tab of the project references dialog.

Alternatively you could use WCF. Create a COM-visible DLL in .Net to act as a wrapper for the WCF communications, so that the VB6 can participate. You could use named pipes: I recommend using the built-in .Net [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx)  in a COM-visible DLL so that the VB6 can call it.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried this, but it really should be simpler than accessing the named pipes API from VB6.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I think the named pipes solution is looking pretty good.  And yeah, creating a wrapper for the named pipes from .net will definitely be simpler than trying to use the API from vb6.